# Which Kipling poem is this an allusion to?

Tags: poetry, identification-request, rudyard-kipling

My great-grandfather wrote lots of poems, and among them a small verse called "Apologies to Rudyard Kipling". It seems that the verse is a travesty on, or reference to, a Kipling poem, but I can't find which one.

My great-grandfather wrote:

> Your dress may be new, and your weapons strange:
> Tanks don’t get gripes, mud-fever or mange;
> But the soldier’s art hasn’t changed a jot:
> You must still wash and shave in a half-pint pot.

I suspect that if I knew the original, I'd recognize the meter or rhymes or so, but so far I've drawn a blank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The allusion may be to ["A Truthful Song"](https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/truthful_song.html). Two verses are of particular interest for the comparison:

- > "Your glazing is new and your plumbing's strange,
  > But otherwise I perceive no change;
  > And in less than a month if you do as I bid
  > I'd learn you to build me a Pyramid!"
- > "Your wheel is new and your pumps are strange,
  > But otherwise I perceive no change;
  > And in less than a week, if she did not ground,
  > I'd sail this hooker the wide world round!"

Both of these verses (each the end of its little section, and thus given more importance) start with the characteristic structure of "Your X is new and your Y strange", something that they share with your great-grandfather's verse. This alone may have been enough for someone familiar with Kipling's works to identify the intended poem, based off of the title of your great-grandfather's as extra prompting.

Beyond such word-level similarity, "A Truthful Song" and your great-grandfather's verse espouse the same overall idea: that while superficial details may change and the world may turn, the fundamentals underlying each occupation stay constant since time immemorial.

Kipling's poem gives two examples of this. First a "BRICKLAYER" and then a "SAILOR" who knows all the tricks of the trade comes up to some workers, stating that their name may be any of several ancient, biblical figures (emphasizing the never-changing-ness) and claiming that since nothing has really changed, they could pull off some great feat of the trade.

Your great-grandfather's verse skips all of the set-up and moves straight to the conclusion's two couplets. But, it hits similar notes. This time the occupation is the "soldier’s art". Something has changed: the introduction of "tanks" which cannot suffer problems of the human body such as "gripes, mud-fever or mange". Some fundamental thing "hasn't changed a jot": they "must still wash and shave in a half-pint pot".

---

Found by searching Google for [`site:https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/* new strange`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.poetryloverspage.com%2Fpoets%2Fkipling%2F*+new+strange); this particular nicely searchable "COMPLETE COLLECTION" of Kipling's poems I found by searching for [`kipling poems`](https://www.google.com/search?q=kipling+poem).

Comment: The poem is from Kipling's book _Rewards and Fairies_ in the chapter "The Wrong Thing."